# $\omega$ is a symplectic form then $L^k_{\omega}:\Omega^q(M)\to \Omega^{q+2k}(M)$ is injective for all $q\leq n-k$ and surjective for all $q\geq n-k$

Tags: differential-forms, symplectic-geometry

Let $(M^{2n},\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold of dimension $2n$. Let $L^k_{\omega}:\Omega^q(M)\to \Omega^{q+2k}(M)$ be the map given by $L^k_{\omega}(\alpha)=\alpha\wedge\omega^k$. Then is it true that $L^k_{\omega}$ is injective for all $q\leq n-k$ and surjective for all $q\geq n-k$?

It seems that this is true, but I could not find a proof for it. Can anyone provide a proof for this, or atleast point out where can I get the proof for this.

Comment: [Crossposted on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/414352/21564).